# Swift: How do I make a scoring system based on how much time is left?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have an app that has a countdown timer. I want it to be such that the faster a user completes the game, the more points they get. For example, the total amount of time given is 120 seconds, so a user who completes the game in 60 seconds gets 120-60=60 points, and a person who finishes the game in 100 seconds gets 120-100=20 points.

Here is a sample of the code I am using to do my countdown timer.

```
func setupGame()  {
seconds = 120
timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func subtractTime() {
    seconds--
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
    if(seconds == 0)  {
        timer.invalidate()
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You're Done!", message: "What would you like to do now?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let shareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Share Pressed")
        }

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Continue Pressed")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("singleViewController") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(shareAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the timer reaches 0, an alert pops up. When this happens, since the time left is 0, I want the score this person gets to be 0 as well. (If you're wondering then how do people stop the game so that they will get a score that's not 0 - I also have a Done button that stops the timer earlier and shows a similar alert)

Now all I need is a way to capture when the timer was stopped, do the math of 120 - *user's time left* = *score*  so that I can display it in a label on the next ViewController.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no "pause" function in your game, a simple solution would be to create a date when the game begins and then check for the number of seconds since that date whenever you want the time transpired.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! My game does not have a pause function. This seems like an ideal solution. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: I'll assume you have some function where you start the game and you begin the timer. Wherever that is, create an NSDate. (Make a reference to it outside of the function first though). Whenever time stops, check the time interval since now on the date variable that you created. The result should be negative (since the date is before now) so you should only need to add it to the total number of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've never heard of NSDate before, so I'm gonna have to learn how to use it. Ahh... The joys of being a newbie!